# sending push notification to multiple users using Parse in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to send push notification to multiple users using parse backend. can i target a friends with Facebook id without creating channel?(in my app i integrated Facebook)

if not possible send me code with creating channel

Comment: "Send me code with creating channel..."?? It sound good. We all here for you? Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse has different possibilities depending on which kind of account you have. I assume you have the free one so you CANNOT send push notifications to specific or multiple users with this kind of account. BUT you can send them through the website controller to just iOS or Android users which is the only option you have with the free account.

I actually encourage you to use channels to do so. I assume you already have the correct initializations as explained in the parse website (https://parse.com/docs/android_guide)

```
// Create our Installation query
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "Giants"); // Set the channel
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("scores", true);

// Send push notification to query
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery);
push.setMessage("Giants scored against the A's! It's now 2-2.");
push.sendInBackground();
```

I ultimately reccomend you to read this guide: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/Android